# Backend instance hours adding up without any backends

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My project is a simple JSON + REST api server which reads/writes to ndb and responds with JSON dictionaries. There are no backends.yaml file in my project. And the contents of my app.yaml are:

```
application: my-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /api/v1/.*
  script: gprofile.application


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: ssl
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

The only other yaml files in my project are a couple of auto-generated index.yaml files.
And yet I have backend hours piling up. As per the dashboard I am accumulating 8 backend instance hours per hour i.e. I am somehow running 8 backends instances. Running `appcfg.py -v backends . list` in my project dir gives the following output:

```
Application: my-app
Warning: This application uses Backends, a deprecated feature that has been replaced by Modules, which offers additional functionality. Please convert your backends to modules as described at: https://developers.google.com/appengine/d
Host: appengine.google.com
2014-11-05 20:23:29,571 INFO appengine_rpc_httplib2.py:268 Too many retries for url https://appengine.google.com/api/backends/list?app_id=my-app
Error 500: --- begin server output ---
Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.
--- end server output ---
```

One more peculiar thing I noticed is that inspite of having no additional yaml files, I still have 3 extra modules defined (apart from the default module). And one of these is marked as `Resident` which means I am unable to shut it down from the dashboard.

Could anyone explain how I have extra modules defined without any extra yaml files and why I am being billed for backends without a backend.yaml.

**Update 1:** I was able to remove the undefined modules by manually deleting them from the dashboard under "Compute > App Engine > Versions". Still can't figure out how they got there in the first place.

**Update 2:** I had defined a couple of backends earlier on during development. But the yaml as well as associated code for them has since been deleted. Is it possible that even after updating my project the old backends are still persisting ? And if so how would I delete them when appcfg can't even list them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have figured out the issue (confirmation of my assumptions would be appreciated)

I think that once a yaml file (defining modules or queues etc) gets added to app-engine, you can't just delete the yaml file and update the project and expect that the existing resources will be automatically removed. They must be removed from the dashboard itself. And even when doing so one must first upload new yaml files which indicate that they are not defined anymore.

For eg. in case of queues, I had to first upload a empty queue.yaml and then only was I able to delete task queues which had been created ages ago during development and never used.

For modules, I had to go to "Compute > App Engine > Versions" and manually delete the modules (even though these modules were not defined anywhere in the source).

The backend hours that I was accumulating were probably because of the `Resident` module because since deleting that, now when I run `appcfg.py backends . list` I get the expected `No backends configured for app: s~my-app` response. The 500 response which I was getting earlier was probably because the module in question had no source code associated with it. And the instance hours were accumulating because app-engine was repeatedly trying to start up this module and failing (since it had no source code)

Once again, this is all based on the assumption that deleting a yaml file doesn't imply resource removal, which is pretty hard to believe. If that is the case then Google should really document this behaviour somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it should choose this by default, I would try adding the "module" key to your app.yaml:

```
   application: my-app
   module: default
   version: 1
   runtime: python27
   api_version: 1
   threadsafe: yes
```

Comment: Yes it takes the default module by default. I was able to delete the extra modules (as updated in my question).

Comment: I think the issues is that removing a yaml file from the source does not imply removal of the feature. For eg. I noticed a redundant task queue as well even though there was no queue.yaml and realised that some other dev added a queue.yaml at some point and then deleted the queue.yaml file. To fix this I had to re-add an empty queue.yaml file and the task queue disappeared from the dashboard. I am guessing the extra modules were also added at some point by the same dev and then just deleted (I can't confirm that because we didn't have any version control that early on)